# What is difference between Transform Rotate and forward Rotate?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want rotated 'transform.forward' with not rotate transform.

but have problem result of 'rot * tf.forward'

I have to make a lot of rotate transform.forward.

I know transform.Rotate is high cost.

Why are those different?

```cs
Transform tf = transform;
Quaternion rot = Quaternion.Euler(90f, 0f, 0f);

Vector3 eulerRot1 = rot * tf.forward * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
tf.roration *= rot;
Vector3 eulerRot2 = tf.forward * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

if(eulerRot1 == eulerRot2)
{
    Debug.Log("Same");
}
else
{
   Debug.Log("Not same");
}
```

Comment: Please, explain what you are trying to do **in the end**. You can't "rotate transform.forward", either you rotate the transform itself (using `transform.Rotate`, which is not that heavy to compute), or you apply a rotation to a vector (transform.forward) in order to do compute something else, without modifying the transform (in this case, you use `Vector3 output = Quaternion.Euler(90, 0, 0) * input;`, without the unnecessary `Mathf.Rad2Deg`);

Comment: Also, keep in mind that quaternion product isn't commutative, meaning `tf.roration *= rot;` (which means `tf.roration = tf.roration * rot;`) is different from `tf.roration = rot * tf.roration`

Comment: @ Hellium Thank you. The plan was to calculate the edge of the camera's viewport. I forgot that the quarterion didn't have a rule of exchange. and now done.

Answer (score 1):

tf.forward does not rotate your gameobject forward. tf.forward is a vector point forward relative to your game object.

transform.Rotate is not high cost, moving your game object directly via it's transform is never expensive. Moving it with it's physics component is expensive